# Python convert lists of unequal length into dictionaries, and then columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with a column of lists with a value and count that I need to convert into a dictionary:
For example:

```
[['a:4', 'b:3', 'd:5'],
['b:1'],
['a:2', 'c:5']]
```

I would then like each item to have a column with the corresponding value as the row value.

```
a    b    c    d
4    3   nan   5
nan  1   nan  nan
2   nan   5   nan
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can change that data format just slightly, so it looks like a list of dicts:

```
x = [{'a':4, 'b':3,'d':5'},
{'b':1},
{'a':2,'c':5}]
```

Then pd.DataFrame(x) will do this automatically:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(x)
     a    b    d    c
0  4.0  3.0  5.0  NaN
1  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN
2  2.0  NaN  NaN  5.0
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1. Change the format.

```py
data = [{lst.split(':')[0]: int(lst.split(':')[1])} for lst in input_data]
```

Step 2, as mentioned by @TimRoberts

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```